# Why does a UIBarButtonItem action not trigger in a separate class?

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote a class that shall handle `UIBarButtonItem` taps. 
The initializer takes a reference to an `UINavigationItem`. All buttons etc. are attached to this  `UINavigationItem`. I tried to connect them with actions (`didPressMenuItem()`), but when I click the button, the action is not triggered (nothing is written to the console nor the breakpoint I set is triggered).

How can I link the `UIBarButtonItem` to the function defined in this class?

```
internal final class NavigationBarHandler {

    // MARK: Properties
    private final var navigationItem: UINavigationItem?

    // MARK: Initializers
    required init(navigationItem: UINavigationItem?) {
        self.navigationItem = navigationItem
    }



    internal final func setupNavigationBar() {
        if let navigationItem = navigationItem {
            let menuImage = UIImage(named: "menu")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            let menuItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: menuImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didPressMenuItem(sender:)))
            menuItem.tintColor = .white

            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuItem
        }
    }

    @objc func didPressMenuItem(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("pressed")
    }

}
```

This is what happens in the view controller to which navigationItem the buttons etc. are attached.

```
class ContactsController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: View Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .red
        self.title = "Kontakte"

        let navigationBarHandler = NavigationBarHandler(navigationItem: self.navigationItem)
        navigationBarHandler.setupNavigationBar()
    }
}
```

Comment: your navigation item is used somewhere?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Yes, `setupNavigationBar()` is called from another view controller. So that VC creates an instance of `NavigationBarHandler` with its navigationItem.

Comment: can you post how are you using your `NavigationBarHandler` class?

Comment: Sure, I'll update my question, just a second.

Comment: That does not work. `navigationItem` is a constant because it is a parameter of `init()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Th problem here is that you're instantiating `NavigationBarHandler` inside `viewDidload()` which is why the memory reference dies after `viewDidLoad()` finishes. What you should do is to create the variable outside like this.

```
class ContactsController: UIViewController {

    var navigationBarHandler: NavigationBarHandler!

    // MARK: View Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .red
        self.title = "Kontakte"

        self.navigationBarHandler = NavigationBarHandler(navigationItem: self.navigationItem)
        navigationBarHandler.setupNavigationBar()
    }
}
```

This way the memory reference stays.

Comment: To be honest, I just got the same idea a few seconds ago after I posted my question. I'll try this out, that makes sense, I'll let you know!

Comment: Glad to be of help! :)